# Notation of award length on CV

Tags: cv, writing-style

If you were to receive a 12 month award, say, starting 1 September 2021, what would be the best or preferred way to notate this on a CV? Would you write Sep 2021 - Aug 2022 or Sep 2021 - Sep 2022?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sep 2021 - Aug 2022 conveys the message more clearly, and considering the date is the first of the month, this makes more sense, if it was the 15th of September 2021- 14th September 2022 I would choose the latter.